# How to set ft=antlr4 in vim? autocmd not working

Tags: vim, antlr4

I've installed a syntax file at `~.vim/after/syntax/antlr4.vim`. And it works great when I manually open a file and then type in:

```
:set ft=antlr4
```

[image]

However, for whatever reason I cannot get it to recognize the file in my `.vimrc`. Here is what I currently have, but it seems to be doing nothing:

```
" Antlr4 highlighting
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.g4 set filetype=antlr4
```

Comment: Try `BufReadPost`

Comment: @phd same -- still get the default `utf-8[unix]` unless manually typing that in.

Comment: `utf-8` and `unix` are not file types — they're `fileencoding` or simply `encoding`; and `fileformat`.

Answer (score 1):

Move this line:

```
au BufRead,BufNewFile *.g4 set filetype=antlr4
```

into that file:

```
~/.vim/ftdetect/antlr4.vim
```

See `:help ftdetect`.

Comment: I'm not sure, I think there's something wrong with my vim configuration. Even basic things I'll add into my vimrc now don't get picked up (but entering in the same thing directly into the opened file works just fine).

Comment: here's an example of what I mean: https://gyazo.com/ae18bd40f4dec269fb36d723865d5efe.

Comment: Earlier, you mentioned "my `.vimrc`". In the recording, it is `vimrc`. You are obviously using a fancy status line plugin while also duplicating features (`showmode`). And then there are so weird comments and mappings in the file. Something tells me you are in way over your head with that config and there are parts of it that you don't understand. I suggest taking a step or two back and rethink the whole thing.

Comment: thanks, yea I wrote the vimrc and all the scripts within it (as well as other files including functions it calls). I just didn't realize it was loading a `vimrc` in a hierarchy and the one I was changing wasn't my default one.